# Get facebook post using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to get information about a post using the facebook c# sdk? I have the post id  so I am trying to query the facebook server using that.

```
string test = VendorShop.Services.Sess.getQueryString("signed_request");
var signed_request_obj  = testClient.ParseSignedRequest( appSecret, test);
var obj = testClient.Get(
    "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/action?q=330203520408060");
```

I have tried a Get using the c# sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get through graph api and passing an access token
// Note :replace **ur_postid** with the actual postid and **ur_accesstoken** with ur facebook access token

```
string test = VendorShop.Services.Sess.getQueryString("signed_request");
var signed_request_obj  = testClient.ParseSignedRequest( appSecret, test);
var obj = testClient.Get(
"https://graph.facebook.com/ur_postid?access_token=ur_accesstoken");
```

// you can use **graph api explorer** to test it